# Why are the details of my todo not saving?

Tags: php, custom-field

I created a todo plugin and when I add a new todo, the title of the todo saves, but the details I write in the wysiwyg do not save and neither does the due date.

Here is the code I believe is responsible for the expected behavior in my-todo-list-fields.php:

```
function mtl_todos_save($post_id){
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave($post_id);
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision($post_id);
    $is_valid_nonce = (isset($_POST['wp_todos_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_todos_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) ? 'true' : 'false';

    if ($is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce) {
      return;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['priority'])) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'priority', sanitize_text_field($_POST['priority']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['details'])) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'details', sanitize_text_field($_POST['details']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['due_date'])) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, 'due_date', sanitize_text_field($_POST['due_date']));
    }
  }

  add_action('save_posts', 'mtl_todos_save');
```

I changed the `$is_valid_nonce` to `!$is_valid_nonce`, but that did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in `add_action('save_posts', 'mtl_todos_save');`, instead it should be: `add_action('save_post', 'mtl_todos_save');`